# Задача на циклы в C

Tags: c++, c, циклы

Вообщем, есть задание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

x, a, n - целые.

Нужно написать код который будет находить результат (С или С ++). Вроде бы написал, но при проверке результатов ошибки. Сижу 2 день не могу найти ришение, возможно кто-то подкинет хотя бы идею для ришения данной задачи.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* ((...(x + a)^2 + a)^2 + ... + a)^2 + a */

int main()
{

    int UserVarN, UserVarA, UserVarX, Result, ResultSum;
    printf("Enter numbers N, X, A: ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &UserVarN, &UserVarX, &UserVarA);

    for(int i = 0; i < UserVarN; i++)
    {
        Result = pow((UserVarX + UserVarA), 2);
        ResultSum += pow((Result + UserVarA), 2);
    }
    Result = ResultSum + UserVarA;

    printf("Result: %d\n", Result);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Зарание спасибо за любую помощь или идеи).

Comment: А в условии сказано, что они все - целые? Нет, проблема не в этом, вы неверно считаете, но стоит ли еще и этим себя ограничивать?

Comment: Чему равно `ResultSum` перед циклом?

Comment: А вы его разве обнуляли?...

Comment: Ну очень быстро будет переполнение...

Answer (score 6):

Я бы делал так:

```
int main()
{

    int N;
    double a, x;
    printf("Enter numbers N, X, A: ");
    scanf("%d %lf %lf", &N, &x, &a);

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) x = (x+a)*(x+a);

    x += a;

    printf("Result: %lf\n", x);
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/L4Nji1 - где именно, в каком месте?

Comment: вероятно потому - что результат выводится как вещественное число, а автоматической проверке не нравятся нули торчащие сбоку.